# audiocodes and webrtc - can't connect the call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I'm beginner in WebRTC. I try to make phone call using audiocodes and WebRTC.
I tried the link [here](https://webrtcdemo.audiocodes.com/sdk/webrtc-api-base/examples/2.click_to_call_phone/usage_1.html). But the call is not connected.

Note:
The phone call initiated from an anonymous user to a registered user.
An anonymous user cannot call other anonymous user.

How can i register **AudioCodes SBC user**

Comment: Can we see a plunkr or similar demo of the code?

Comment: https://webrtcdemo.audiocodes.com/sdk/webrtc-api-base/examples/2.click_to_call_phone/usage_1.html
I tried ths one.

Comment: I believe this isn't a coding problem then. You might want to ask on super-user maybe

Comment: Yeah! I know this not a coding problem. The problem is how to register *SBC user* ?

Answer (score 0):

It's my example ;-)

Тhis example partially works, please use Chrome browser and open javascript console: Ctrl/Shift/I and select console tab

After click (if you have and enable microphone) the phone starts calling to Audiocodes example SBC.

Here used SIP protocol to establish call:
send SIP INVITE message to SBC from anonymous user.
(you can see it in javascript console)

Problem here that user "SantaClaus" is not registered in our example SBC, so will be returned SIP response 404 'User not found'

Sorry, we simply don't have telephone operator or some automatic answer machine in our example SBC to send you voice response.

The next example is more flexible. [Run click-to-call example (with HTML form)](https://webrtcdemo.audiocodes.com/sdk/webrtc-api-base/examples/2.click_to_call_phone/usage_2.html)

You can type user name, and change SBC address.
It is used by our vendors at demonstrations.

Only our WebRTC developers have accounts on the example SBC. 
You are welcome !